# Count and print matching values in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I can't use patterns or folding, per the parameters of the assignment, of which this is a toy example of a particular approach to a larger problem.

When I run the code, I get a '0', naturally. So the question is, how do I get the final value of a_count?

```
fun num_counter(numbers: int list, a_number: int) =
     let val count = 0
             in
                 let fun count_num(numbers: int list, a_count: int) =
         if null numbers
         then 0
         else if (hd numbers) = a_number
         then count_num(tl numbers, count + 1)
         else count_num(tl numbers, count)
     in
     count       
     end
     end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Your recursive function `count_num` is never called.
2. Your recursion terminates by returning `0` instead of the result
   you've acumulated so far (`a_count`).
3. There is some confusion between parameter `a_count` that, as I
   understood holds the number of occurences of `a_number` and `count`
   declared at the second line.

Here is some correction to it:

```ml
fun num_counter(numbers: int list, a_number: int) = let
    fun count_num(numbers: int list, count: int) =
      if null numbers
      then count  (*  reached the end of the list =>
                      returned the number of occurences computed  *)
      else if (hd numbers) = a_number
      then count_num(tl numbers, count + 1)
      else count_num(tl numbers, count)
in
    count_num (numbers, 0)  (*  first call of count_num,
                                count initiated to 0  *)
end;
```

Also note that you can use pattern matching to enhance readability of
your recursive function:

```ml
fun num_counter(numbers: int list, a_number: int) =
  let fun count_num([], count) = count
        | count_num(i :: tl, count) =
          count_num(tl, if i = a_number then count + 1 else count)
  in
      count_num (numbers, 0)
  end;
```

Comment: That works. I hadn’t quite figured out when goes into the ‘in’ clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it shorter using a fold:

```
fun num_counter (numbers, a_number) =
    let fun count (b_number, total) =
            if a_number = b_number
            then total + 1
            else total
    in foldl count 0 numbers
    end
```

Here `foldl` takes three arguments: the function `count` that accumulates the result when visiting each number, `b_number` in `numbers`, the initial value for `total` being `0` and the numbers to fold over, `numbers`. When `foldl` has visited the last number, it uses the last accumulation in `total` as the result.

`foldl` is itself defined [like this](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/List.sml#L87):

```
fun foldl f e []      = e
  | foldl f e (x::xr) = foldl f (f(x, e)) xr
```

Or you can `filter` and take the `length` which costs a bit more:

```
fun num_counter (numbers, a_number) =
    length (filter (fn b_number => a_number = b_number) numbers)
```